# how to get Kendo().TextBoxFor value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, textbox

I'm using Kendo UI TextBoxFor such as:

```
@Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(model => model.ID).HtmlAttributes(new {  @class = "fixed-width" }).Name("ID")
```

but I am unable to fetch the value in javascript:

```
var id = ????
```

any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

A TextBox used with `@(Html.Kendo().TextBox()` or `@(Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(m => m.Property)` is just a helper method to create an input field. You can use jquery to get all fields with `$('.k-textbox')`.

You may also add an id to get specific text boxes:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(m => m.Property)
   .HtmlAttributes(new
   {
       id = "text-box-property-id"
   })
)
```

To get the value on client side with Javascript you could use jquery.

```
$('#text-box-property-id').val()
```

Comment: later versions of kendo ui break this

Answer (score 3):

you can retrieve the value this way using JQuery:

```
$('#ID').data('kendoTextBox').value();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.
I have already tried the same, but it doesn't work.

Comment: you can also use below code to get value of kendo textbox in jquery
   $('#ID').val();